# No column break in new sections

Tags: two-column, columns, columnbreak

I'm working in a two column article. At the end of the first column I have a new section, LaTeX is breaking the column and start the new section in the second column. How can I force LaTeX to fill all the first column before start the new section in the second column? i.e. Put the section heading in the first column

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\section{Section}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: LaTeX will not put a lonely section heading at the end of the column. This is a feature not a bug.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Enlarging the page**

A possible solution is to use the command `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` to locally enlarge the page with one line. Of cause you may experiment with other values. On my system `0.25\baselineskip`, was enough to move the section and two line to the previous column.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\section{Section}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

**2. Reducing the space above \section**

If enlarging the page is not an option, you can reduce the space above and below the section by putting a `\vspace`-command with negative value before and after the `\section`-command. However, this approach destroy some of the ideas behind LaTex.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
%\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\vspace{-0.25\baselineskip}  %% ---> **Here it is**
\section{Section}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you will see, reducing with `0.25\baselineskip` is enough on my system, but it may be that you have to increase the value on your system, depending on your setup.

**NB!**  You may of cause still use the package [multicol](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) for grid setting and column balancing.

**NB!**  *A final warning: This type of tinkering should be the absolutely last thing you do after you have finalised all editing and proofreading.*

Comment: as for decreasing the space *following* the section heading with `\vspace`, this must be done with great care to avoid leaving a condition under which the break could occur between the section heading and the text.  better would be to clone the `\section` definition, perhaps calling it `\tightsection`, and modifying the values for the spaces above and below in the new definition.